# Is it possible to activate bluetooth from code

Tags: blackberry

hey in my application i have to give user an option called "BLUETOOTH"

Is it possible that i can put it ON or OFF from my code

i have no idea....

Am i doing right or just trying to do unnecessary work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the Bluetooth radio is on or off using [LocalDevice.isPowerOn()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/bluetooth/LocalDevice.html#isPowerOn()) but there isn't a direct way to turn on the radio from code.  However, if you call [DiscoveryAgent.startInquiry()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryAgent.html) when the radio is off, it will prompt the user to turn Bluetooth on.

Comment: Marc, is there any way to know when the Bluetooth of the device is turned on (like `WLANConnectionListener` informs about the WiFi connectivity)? Please let me know.